# lua_pushstring random bitflip corruptions

Tags: lua

I am seeing a very odd issue and I am wondering if anyone else is seeing it or has had a similar expereince.

I am using lua 5.3.5 and using native and lua code.
I currentlyu use `lua_pushlstring` to push a large buffer into lua.
I know the string is a bit wasteful, but it works.
Over the last year I have noticed some abnormalities in my diagnostics data.
Things were not quite makeing sense, so I added a CRC that is calculated on the native side and then passed to lua.
Armed with this, I was able to enhance my diagnostics and soon discovered that there was random bitflips in my string when checking it in lua.
As its just a few bits, it doesnt seem like a normal heap currption (I would expect some larger sections).

Unfortantly I am only seeing this in a very small percentage of devices and I havent not been able to reproduce it consistantly.

I am wondering if anyone else has experienced this?
(sorry I cannot provide more specific examples)

Comment: For binary data, you should use `lua_pushlstring`. When you use `lua_pushstring`, it stops at the first zero byte, because it calls `strlen`.

Comment: May be just bad memory? After pushstring you can get pointer to the newly allocated stringand check crc

Comment: @ihf, yes you are 100% correct. I misspoke/wrote i am using lua_pushlstring! Sorry about that and thank you for the advice and correction.

Comment: @moteus I was thinking the same at first and that actually why i added the CRC. The thing is the instance count i am seeing feels too high for it to be bad memory.